# Youtube API topic id search not working

Tags: search, youtube-api, freebase

I am trying to search using YouTube Data API for a particular topic id that is '/m/06j8x'. I am getting 0 results.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&topicId=%2Fm%2F06j8x&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Result:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"CuSCwMPVmgi8taDtE2LV6HdgkN0/ghbGp-0DJeq3NChI2_0bgqHroaA\"",
 "regionCode": "IN",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

While when I check the same for a particular video id I get the relevant topic id in the topicDetails:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"CuSCwMPVmgi8taDtE2LV6HdgkN0/EmFw8XpBwZEL9mvH8a_hdr9d_Sg\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"CuSCwMPVmgi8taDtE2LV6HdgkN0/3BJWWacFULs5wKF-_-SeORU2QP4\"",
   "id": "uONflvUz6sc",
   "topicDetails": {
    "topicIds": [
     "/m/06j8x"
    ],
    "relevantTopicIds": [
     "/m/074ft",
     "/m/04rlf",
     "/m/06x7h_",
     "/m/04rlf"
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

I am not able to figure out why this is happening. Is it because youtube only searches in relevant topic id's?

Comment: I would check your topic id its probably incorrect I didn't get any data back for that one  but I am for /m/045c7b for example.

Comment: If my topic id was incorrect then how it is showing in the video id topic details? Check out topic details for 'uONflvUz6sc'

Comment: And the video isn't private either I checked.   This is strange.

Comment: @AkshanshGupta where can i find the topics Ids please ??